# Actionmailer SMTP Server Response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, qmail

When sending mail through actionmailer, the actionmailer gets a response from the SMTP server, when its ok, or when its wrong. Is there a way to retrieve this response after sending a mail?
Also when no errors are thrown by the SMTP server?

Our qmail mail server throws a handler id which we want to use for tracing e-mails.

As an example, the server response is this :

250 ok 1308235825 qp 17832

Answer (score 8):

Set `return_response: true` in the smtp settings and call `message.deliver!` instead of `deliver`. This returns the SMTP server response, a `Net::SMTP::Response`, which contains the server response you're looking for.

If you need a log of all responses from the connection with the server, not just the final result, you'll need to dig into Net::SMTP.

Comment: This break some test for me, because it change the class of returned object. How should be change/override the returning value in tests when return_response is true ?

Comment: @duleorlovic that depends on the purpose of your tests doesn't it. basically if you call the bang form `deliver!` you should handle a `Net::SMTP::Response` as the result.  `result.success?` is a bult-in you could use. See http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP/Response.html

Comment: Why isn't `return_response` on by default?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the the source you can define an observer:

in [base.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L360)

```
  # Register an Observer which will be notified when mail is delivered.
  # Either a class or a string can be passed in as the Observer. If a string is passed in
  # it will be <tt>constantize</tt>d.
  def register_observer(observer)
    delivery_observer = (observer.is_a?(String) ? observer.constantize : observer)
    Mail.register_observer(delivery_observer)
  end
```

So you could use some code like this in an initialization file:

```
class MailObserver
  def self.delivered_email(message)
    logger_info "Sent Message: #{message}"
  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.register_observer(MailObserver)
```

That will log sent mail and you can see if you can get the headers or response from the sent mail object.

Comment: Well i want all responses from the server, even when there is no error. Our qmail mail server throws a handler id which we want to use for tracing e-mails.