# Response from SMTP server with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, amazon-web-services, smtp, actionmailer

How could I get the response from an SMTP server in Ruby on Rails using ActionMailer, when I send an email with the `Mailer.deliver` method?

I found the [Actionmailer SMTP Server Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374648/actionmailer-smtp-server-response) answer but it doesn't work... Any idea?

I need it because [AWS SES return a message ID](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-response-codes.html) through, and it's the only way to get the message linked to a bounce or spam report they provide after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you get the smtp in way like this

```
response = Mail.your_mail().deliver
```

and it isn't getting the response that you need, try deliver_now!

```
response = Mail.your_mail().deliver_now!
pp response.message
```

This will show you the result: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 3lG8S16Khmz6ZhXq

I also configured the smtp settings on my Mail.rb

```
delivery_options = {   user_name: 'email@server.com.br',
                       password: 'mypassword',
                       authentication: :login,
                       address: 'smtp.mycompany.com.br',
                       port: 2525,
                       domain: 'mycompany.com.br',
                       return_response: true
                    }
```

Comment: Does this " Ok: queued as ..."  message means that the e-mail was successfully delivered for sure?

Comment: @carla that message just means that the email was correctly sent to the SMTP server, however, if you need to ensure that the email was delivered that's something called "Observer". Research about Action Mailer Observer and you'll get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If using gem "aws-ses" you can get the message id with:

```
response = your_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_now!
response.message_id # => "010601531c886c55-6c2f30fc-4237-4294-9029-b60b2d44a691-000000@email.amazonses.com"
```

For me `deliver`, `deliver_now` and `deliver_now!` work in the same way

EXTRA:
If for some chance you are using devise you can get the ID too:

```
#[app/model/user.rb]
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  # Override send_devise_notification stated in devise/REAMDE.txt
  def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)                      
    response = devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_now
    response.message_id #=> "010601531c8-86c...000000@email.amazonses.com"
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: While using `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :aws_sdk` the code `response.message_id` did return the id, thanks =)